# Как правильно расположить эти стрелки?

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Всем привет! Как реализовать такие стрелки, чтобы на адаптиве не пришлось поправлять каждый пиксель? это у меня слик слайдер[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сейчас они у меня сделаны через before, after. как их расположить в один блок, если у меня в файле html ничего не прописано

Comment: Ну, вообще в slick`е они изначально спозиционированы относительно слайдера слева и справа. Ничего на адаптиве поправлять не надо. С какой именно проблемой Вы столкнулись? Уточните в вопросе и приведите пример Вашего кода.

Comment: да, но они позиционируются по центру и относительно контейнера с галлереей, а мне надо внизу, как на картинке, поэтому правая стрелка постоянно съезжает. кода нет, я взяла библиотеку слик и изменила там стрелки через content

Comment: @Лина нужно добавить в параметры слика prevArrow, nextArrow, appendDots, придумать им классы, в html создать кнопки с классами и потом кастомизировать их https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#:~:text=Element%2C%20jQuery%20object)-,prevArrow,-string%20(html%7CjQuery